# Getting the unicode value of a char in VB

Tags: vba, unicode

How can I get the unicode value of a char?

For example, I know that I can do this with ascii:

```
i = Asc("a") // i == 97 (correct)
```

What if I have a unicode char though?

```
i = Asc("•") // i == 149 (incorrect... should return 8226)
```

Obviously the second example doesn't work since that character is not in the Ascii set. Is there an equivalent function that I can use which will return `8226` instead of the incorrect result `149`?

I'm doing this in Outlook 2003, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What about [AscW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262678(VS.60).aspx) ?

Comment: +1 but you've linked to the Vb.net docs. Here's VB6 instead (VBA would be even better) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262678(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by RC. helped me a lot but I had issues with the `AscW()` function sometimes returning negative values.

In my case the problem appeared when working with Chinese characters.

I found a work around on the web:

```
Function CharToUnicode(strChar As String)

    Dim lngUnicode As Long

    lngUnicode = AscW(strChar)

    If lngUnicode < 0 Then
        lngUnicode = 65536 + lngUnicode
    End If

    CharToUnicode = lngUnicode

End Function
```